servicio SOAP --- soapenv:Server.userException -
Estoy intentando cancelar un CFDI a través de un servicio SOAP proporcionado por Edicom. Al hacer la petición, recibo el siguiente error:


<soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
    <faultstring>com.edicom.ediwinws.service.cfdi.CFDiException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.</faultstring>
    <detail>
        <ns1:fault xmlns:ns1="http://cfdi.service.ediwinws.edicom.com">
            <ns1:cod>201</ns1:cod>
            <ns1:text>javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.</ns1:text>
        </ns1:fault>
        <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">cfdi01</ns2:hostname>
    </detail>
</soapenv:Fault>



El error principal parece estar relacionado con un problema de comunicación (Could not send Message.) cuando intento enviar la solicitud SOAP
segun el codigo de error que me lanza , significa "201 No se ha podido cancelar los comprobantes.
• No se ha podido cancelar los UUIDs especificados." , saben que podria estar pansando , ya verique que  todos los valores de la petición se estén tomando.
